# Rust binary-heap or priority queue on struct with 2 ways to order

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust, and I want to implement something similar to a priority queue with a custom comparator like in Java.

Say I have a struct like this:

```
pub struct Dog {
    pub age:    u32,
    pub weight:  u32,
}
impl Dog {
    pub fn new(age: u32, weight: u32) -> Self {
        Self {
            age: age,
            weight: weight,
        }
    }
}
```

How do I implement 2 different priority queues or binary heaps that are able to order just based on one of the attributes, like say an ageHeap and a weightHeap.

Say I have something like this

```
let d1 = Dog::new(1,3);
let d2 = Dog::new(2,2);
let d3 = Dog::new(3,1);
```

If I pass into the ageHeap, when popping, I would get d1,d2,d3. If I pass into the weightHeap, when popping, I would get d3,d2,d1.

Comment: Why don't you use the `age` attribute for sorting in your `ageHeap` implementation, and `weight` in your `weightHeap`?

Comment: Step 1 is usually [`impl Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html) for these.

Comment: @mkrieger1 would this mean I need one wrapper for a heap to use ord on age and then another wrapper for weight?

Comment: I don't know if you need one. I don't know the code for your heaps.

Comment: Well I mean I don't have code for any heaps I'm wondering how I would implement this behavior for 2 heaps, like in Java I would just make 2 custom comparators and then I could just pass those into a heap, but Rust doesn't have something similar so how would I mimic this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library [`BinaryHeap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BinaryHeap.html) uses the stored type's [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html) as its comparator, so you can't change it for a single type. You can create a wrapper type for each additional comparator you want to use.

```rs
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct WeightDog(pub Dog);

impl Ord for WeightDog {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        self.0
            .weight
            .cmp(&other.0.weight)
            .then_with(|| self.0.age.cmp(&other.0.age))
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for WeightDog {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<std::cmp::Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}
```

You can also create a binary heap type that takes a comparator in its constructor. This is what the [binary-heap-plus](https://docs.rs/binary-heap-plus/0.5.0/binary_heap_plus/index.html) crate does.

```rs
let comparator = binary_heap_plus::KeyComparator(|dog: &Dog| (dog.weight, dog.age));
let mut heap = binary_heap_plus::BinaryHeap::from_vec_cmp(vec![d1, d2, d3], comparator);
```

Both the standard library's heap and binary-heap-plus's heap are max-heaps, so these will pop items in the opposite order than what you specified. You can use a different comparator for a min-heap, or wrap your comparator in [`Rev`](https://docs.rs/compare/0.1.0/compare/struct.Rev.html).